# Extract a substring between double quotes with regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
"   @Test(groups = {G1}, description = "adc, def")"
```

I want to extract "adc, def" (without quotes) using regexp in Java, how should I do?

Answer (score 16):

If you really want to use regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\\"(.*)\\\".*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("your \"string\" here");
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Explanation:

```
.*   - anything
\\\" - quote (escaped)
(.*) - anything (captured)
\\\" - another quote
.*   - anything
```

However, it's a lot easier to not use regex:

```
"your \"string\" here".split("\"")[1]
```

Comment: is there a way without using a regex?

Comment: @cody `string.split("\"")[1]`

Comment: thx @Doorknob, but I should've been more specific:

Say I have a String such as:
String oz = "She said, \"lions, tigers, and bears\". Afterword she exclaimed, \"Oh my!\".";

So how can I splice out the "lions, tigers, and bears" AND "Oh my!" quotes, without regex?

Comment: @cody `String[] arr = string.split("\""); //first string is in arr[1] and second is in arr[3]`

Comment: But this only works because we know the string and how many quotes it has. What do you suggest for a random text with a random number of quotes in it? I was looking for something more like a quote finder method...?

Comment: @cody `String[] arr = string.split("\""); for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2) { /* use arr[i] */ }`

Comment: @Doorknob Why do you need to escape the quote mark for regex, it's not a special char. Just need an escape for the string (\").

Comment: This is wrong cause if it there are two quotes strings it will match both.
Example: My "love" is "great" will match "love" is "great" and NOT "love" and "great"

Answer (score 3):

Actually you'll get the `IllegalStateException`

```
public class RegexDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\\"(.*)\\\".*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("your \"string\" here");
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

It gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:485)
    at RegexDemo.main(RegexDemo.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Before using `group()`, you need to call `find()` or `matches()`.

Simple test, for example:

```
public class RegexTest {
    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void testIllegalState() {
        String string = new String("your \"string\" here");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\\"(.*)\\\".*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }

    @Test
    public void testLegalState() {
        String string = new String("your \"string\" here");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\\"(.*)\\\".*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        if(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```