# Filtering string between double or single quotations with varying spaces

Tags: java, regex, string

I have these two variations of this string

```
 name='Anything can go here'
 name="Anything can go here"
```

where name= can have spaces like so

```
name=(text)
name =(text)
name = (text)
```

I need to extract the text between the quotes, I'm not sure what's the best way to approach this, should I just have mechanism to cut the string off at quotes and do you have an example where I wont have many case handling, or should I use regex.

Comment: You can go to http://stackoverflow.com/q/14574689/4725592

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wanting to get `Anything can go here` whether it's in between single quotes or double quotes.  `Regex` has the capabilities of doing this regardless of the spaces before or after the "=" by using the following pattern:

```
"[\"'](.+)[\"']"
```

Breakdown:

- `[\"']` - Character class consisting of a double or single quote
- `(.+)` - One or more of any character (may or may not match line terminators stored in capture group 1
- `[\"']` - Character class consisting of a double or single quote

In short, we are trying to capture anything between single or double quotes.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
        "name='Anything can go here'",
        "name = \"Really!  Anything can go here\""
    ));

    for (String d : data) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[\"'](.+)[\"']").matcher(d);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Anything can go here
Really!  Anything can go here
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question exactly but I'll give it my best shot:

If you want to just assign a variable `name2` to the string inside the quotation marks then you can easily do :

```
String name = 'Anything can go here';
String name2= name.replace("'","");
name2 = name2.replace("\"","");
```

Comment: let me know if this isn't what you're after